# Chrome fails to load the page while running any automation script.Code works in FF /Edge

Tags: python, java, selenium-webdriver

Installed the latest chrome drivers/tried chrome options.Cant figure out why any automated script  doesnt work on chrome.Works fine on FF Edge

Adding chrome options/updating drivers doesnt help either.Python Robotframe/Java Selenium nothing runs on chrome just shows the blank page (Not Secure data:,)

---

*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
TestCase1: Verify Login page title

Open Browser   url=https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/    browser=chrome  executable_path=C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe
Maximize Browser Window                                               ${title}    Log Title
Log   ${title}    console=True
Close Browser

Comment: Can you edit your question and share your code, error from the console in the form of text?

Comment: SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7DC0C7062+63090]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF7DC032CB2]

Comment: TestCase1: Verify Login page title
    Open Browser   url=https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/    browser=chrome  #executable_path=C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe      (added the latest chromedriver in the mentioned path)

Comment: Share the properly formatted code in the question not as a comment.